# How to Determine XML Element's Children Based on Value of Attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, xml-attribute

I'm using Eclipse IDE to build an XML Schema for processing by JAXB, but I'm getting a validation error on the following:

```
    <xsd:element name="testEl">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="testElChild">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="tec1"/>
                                <xsd:element name="tec2"/>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:attribute name="type" use="required" fixed="yes"/>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="testElChild">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="tec3"/>
                                <xsd:element name="tec4"/>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:attribute name="type" use="required" fixed="no"/>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
```

Basically, I'm trying to specify that if the type attribute of element `testElChild` has a value of "yes" then it should contain child elements `tec1` and `tec2`, but if the type attribute has a value of "no" then it should contain child elements `tec3` and `tec4`.

What is wrong with the above schema and/or how do I go about accomplishing the intention with valid XML schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help much that you **show the validation error** you get. I can only assume something about the fact you have the same element name `testElChild` in both choices.

To fix it, I recommend you follow two of the best practices in writing XML schemas:

- [Avoid anonymous types](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-avoid-anonymous-types/): it is easier to troubleshoot if you start with named types instead of anonymous types; then, when everything works and you are still determined to use anonymous types, you could translate with anonymous types (if used only once);
- [Use polymorphism instead of xsd:choice](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-tip-xsdchoice/index.html): you define an abstract type `TestElChild` for instance, and one extension type per choice you had, e.g. `NoTypeTestElChild` and `YesTypeTestElChild`.

It may be tedious at first but will same you some trouble on the long term. If you have issues writing the XSD according to these practices, let us know.

Comment: The validation error is "cos-element-consistent: Error for type '#AnonType_testEl'. Multiple elements with name 'testElChild', with different types, appear in the model group."

Comment: OK, it seems close to what I assumed, recommendations in my answer should help fix it.